# PouchDB and linked documents

Tags: pouchdb, documents, database, nosql

In my pouchdb database I've two different types of documents.

Type 1:

```
{ 
  class : example,
  type : one
}
```

Type 2:

```
{ 
  surname : Lancester,
  forename : Burt,
  class : 'id of related doc of type 1',
  type : two
}
```

Now I'm looking for a way to get a view like this (or similar):

```
{ 
  surname : Lancester,
  forename : Burt,
  classname : { class : example } - or only class : example 
}
```

I'm quite new with pouchDB and I can't find the right way at the moment. May you help me, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i believe you want to join two documents and create a new one.Joins are not supported.Why don't you use the last class type to store data ?

Comment: I know what I'm looking for is like a join. But when I store data in the type two documents, I have to make changes at different places. That is, what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You could store type 1 documents with an id of c1_? where ? is a unique identifier (no need for for a type:).

Then for type 2 documents use an id starting c2_

Assuming you already have type 1 documents created you can present a list of these i.e. all type c1_ when creating your type 2 document and then assign the selected type 1 id as class.  Of course you then need a lookup to the actual data every time you want a view of it.

Alternatively, you can store the entire type 1 document with or without it's id (and other info such as _rev) as an object within the type 2 document.

It all depends whether you want the type 1 data to be static or dynamic and how efficient you want the data storage to be i.e. normalisation of the data.